# Do I need to use geth --rpc with ethminer?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ethminer

I've seen some tutorials where people do

```
geth account new
geth --rpc
ethminer -G -F your.poolurl.com:port/WALLET --farm-recheck 200
```

And others that are just simply

```
geth account new
ethminer -G -F your.poolurl.com:port/WALLET --farm-recheck 200
```

What is the purpose of `geth --rpc`? Do I really need it to start mining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of geth --rpc?

That command starts the HTTP JSON-RPC client.

JSON-RPC is a stateless, light-weight remote procedure call (RPC) protocol.

> Do I really need it to start mining and make a profit?

In order to run ethminer in farming mode you need to connect to the geth node. The `-F` option does it.

```
-F,--farm <url>  Put into mining farm mode with the work server at URL (default: http://127.0.0.1:8545)
```

Comment: So if I use the `-F` option with `ethminer` I don't need to `geth --rpc`?

Comment: if you provide an url of own geth node then you need an rpc option.

Answer (score 1):

The --rpc flag opens your port to RPC connection, with port 8545 by default. It is not required for mining.
--rpc is used for external (or internal) connection, like with web3js. You can connect to the node and send calls/transactions using this node.

More information [about JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC)